# Want to pass multiple URL in karateDSL Scenario with same Path

Tags: api, karate

Multiple URL i am going to pass in background for each url path should run scenario

Background:

```
 * header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
```

Background:

```
  * header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }

    Scenario: Creates the webservices api page

    Given path 'rest/activescript/about'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def B = response
    * print B
```

**Actual Result** : is last url in background will consider in scenario to execute

**expected Result** : all Url in background should run with diff scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. Though I'm not sure it is recommended to do this. The url is usually defined in karate-config.js for the whole run.

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario called multiple times
    * url '<newUrl>'
    * header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
    Given path 'rest/activescript/about'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def B = response
    * print B

    Examples:
    |newUrl                                           |
    |URL1|
    |URL2 |
```

Comment: Yep its working with little correction  * url  '<newurl>' , i will check same in karate- config.js